# jQuery waypoints trigger

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-waypoints

Here's the code : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/133/)

Issue : I want the element to `bounceInDown` when I scroll over to it which it clearly does. But, you notice that the element is already there for a second and then after it does the animation `bounceInDown` Is there any solution for this. 
Also, I'm following this template [Halcyon Days BootStrap Template](http://tympanus.net/Freebies/HalcyonDaysTemplate/#). If you head over to the link and scroll down, you'll see that the "Creative Portfolio Theme" is not there at first but when you scroll over to it, it `fadeInLeft`
Which in my case is not happening. I want to deal with that. 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I've answered the 1st part of your question below. As for the second part, there's not really enough detail to know what's going on. Could you include the relevant parts of your code? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your offset value is at `75%`, which means the callback won't trigger until it reaches that point in the viewport. Change the offset to `100%` and you'll see what you're expecting.

[See example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/135/)

**EDIT**

Perhaps you should hide the element before it gets animated, and show it when animation begins. You can do this pretty easily with CSS:

```
#intro .wp1 {
    opacity: 0;
}

#intro .wp1.animated {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/136/)

Comment: I've changed the offset to 100% in my original page and now, it's not even doing the animation :/

Comment: You can see that the "we create the awesome" section is already there for a sec (if offset is set to 75%) and then after a sec it does the animation. I want it to not to be present at first, but It should bounceInDown when I scroll over to it

Comment: Hmm yes I see. Try the above suggestion in the edit.

Comment: YES! It worked. okay now if we want more than one element to be animated.. The opacity thing doesn't work with that, see : http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/137/ (view in full screen) you can also refer to the template and see how their icons smoothly fadeInUp one by one after short delays

Comment: That's because the parent ID should be `#features`, not `#intro`, in your CSS. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/138/) :)

Comment: yeah, sorry.. But the delay part is still causing trouble! :/ i want the two circle appear after the first one with delays

Comment: This is now beyond the scope of your original question, you should really mark this answer as accepted and ask a new one with all the relevant details for the new question.

Comment: help me with the delays, please :)

Comment: Dude, tbh... This question got noticed, its  a miracle. Now I've posted a new question regrding the delays but nobody is answering it... I give you the link to the other question, help me out Bro :) you can answer it there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279025/jquery-waypoints-delays