# jQuery waypoints delays

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I have three elements that I want to `fadeInUp` when I scroll over to them. But, now comes the delay part, I want the two elements appear after the first one has appeared. But, the problem is that, it's not happening as expected, they are all showing up at the same time. 
Here's the fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/138/embedded/result/)

I want the two yellow circles to appear after the first one with delays of 0.5s and 1s respectively. I've tried adding the class "delay-05s" and "delay-1s" to the elements but for a reason, It's not happening.
Also, here's a template that I'm trying to mimic, go over there and you'll see : [Halcyon Days BootStrap Template](http://tympanus.net/Freebies/HalcyonDaysTemplate/#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very nearly there.

Adding classes to use CSS animation delays was the right way to go, but those classes weren't defined anywhere!

Just include some CSS to apply the animation delays:

```
.delay-05s {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.delay-1s {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/141/

Comment: I knew I could rely on ya